# Onedrive sync does not detect remote changes - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, synchronization, onedrive

Some time ago I followed these instructions https://gist.github.com/starlinq/0f98c6d9339497bb8ac42d67f66f60eb to install OneDrive on the remote Ubuntu 18.04 machine of my university. Although incredibly slow, it was all well and good: the sync between my local and remote machine through OneDrive server was carried out properly by the `onedrive --synchronization` command. Yesterday I deleted couple of folders containing a bunch of codes (there were some git repository which were messing up onedrive sync) and some images from my local machine. The subsequent synchronization with the remote OneDrive cloud went fine. Today, I tried to sync my remote machine with OneDrive and there is no chance I can see those folders disappear when the sync command is launched. I tried `onedrive --synchronization --resync` on the remote machine with no luck since the only result was re-upload the dead folders from my remote machine where they were still there clinging on for dear life.

Any clue/suggestion about what is preventing my remote OneDrive machine to sync with OneDrive server? I did also try `onedrive --synchronize --download-only` and `onedrive --synchronize --force` but all I get is the standard sequence:

```
Configuration file successfully loaded
Configuring Global Azure AD Endpoints
Initializing the Synchronization Engine ...
Syncing changes from OneDrive ...
Uploading differences of ~/OneDrive
Uploading new items of ~/OneDrive
```

while if I try `onedrive --synchronize --verbose -v+` I get hundreds of messages like

```
[DEBUG] No Strict Matching Enforced
[DEBUG] Checking file: ./webSite/themes/academic/data/webpack_assets.json
[DEBUG] skip_file evaluation for: /webSite/themes/academic/data/webpack_assets.json
[DEBUG] Checking file: ./webSite/themes/academic/theme.toml
```

although the only "skip_dir" in the .config/ondrive/config file are `skip_dir = "thesis|heavyData"`.

Answer (score 0):

in the config file, try and set `local-first` option to `true`

Ref: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abraunegg/onedrive/master/config